# How should I set up a Tumblr blog at a WordPress Page?

Tags: pages, redirect, tumblr, wp-list-pages

I am developing a site for a client, let's call it `whatever.com`. He wants to have his Tumblr blog at `whatever.com/blog`. (Tumblr lets you name the URL at which your Tumblr page will be served, and if it's a site root, you adjust your domain's A-Record, which obviously I can't do here.)

Right now I have a blank page called `blog` so that it shows up in the nav using `wp_list_pages()`, but I'm guessing this won't work unless I do some fiddling elsewhere.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does the client want the Tumblr content to actually show up inside of the WordPress site, or does the link on the nav menu just point to the Tumblr site, completely unrelated to the WP install?

Comment: Unless you want to do something really hacky like putting an iframe onto that page which points at the Tumblr blog, there's no way to do this properly. Tell him to just use WP instead.

Comment: @Joshua He wants it to point to the tumblr site. Perhaps I can hard-code a link and use `.htaccess` to rewrite? But to me, that counts as hacky. Better to just use WordPress, methinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, given that it's okay to send the visitor to an entirely different site, but you are trying to get it to show up as a page, I would suggest adding it to a menu.

You are probably already aware, but when you are modifying menus (Appearance > Menus) there is a box on the left side called "Custom Links," which just like they sound, allow you to add something directly to the menu that can go anywhere. Add an entry using this that goes to the Tumblr blog and use that menu (whether it be primary or secondary) wherever you need to display the pages AND the Tumblr link. This avoids `.htaccess` conflicts and is the "natural" way to do things, but does restrict it to only being in menus.

Might be missing something here on how Tumblr recognizes the URL and the DNS issues, but from the WordPress side of things, that's how I would go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how Tumblr works with domains, but it seems to me you could create a physical /blog directory, which will override WordPress. Then you can make that work with Tumblr however they do it. To put the item back into the menu using `wp_list_pages`, try to the Page Links To plugin to create a post or page that links to /blog: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/

Comment: Tumblr only redirects to domains (via A-record), so this doesn't exactly work for what I'm doing, but that's still useful info. Thanks!